# What would a world look like if everything was a billion times more massive?

Tags: biology, physics, astrophysics, infrastructure, virtual-reality

All atoms are still the same size/mass - it's just that the Earth, people, grass, bugs, etc - everything is more massive by a billion times.

So since the Earth would be a billion times more massive, the sun would have to be as well - aside from the fact that the sun would have a much shorter life-span due to its enormous size, the Earth would be distant from the sun, relative to the distance it is today. As in, the temperature on Earth would be the same.

Would the world on Earth look more or less same?

Or (intentionally exaggerated) would a snap of a finger cause a black hole to occur due to the super intense force and pressure acted upon the atoms on our fingers?

As the Earth spins, would it have a different effect since it's still trying to rotate once every 24 hours but the amount of mass that it's rotating is a billion times more?

Even though humans are now a billion times more massive than they are, would they even be able to stand up since the Earth itself would have tremendous more gravitational force?

Would car collisions cause super novas sending waves throughout the universe?

These are just some questions about a world a billion times more massive than ours.

Comment: you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”. Explicitly out of scope according to our [help]

Comment: I was going to type an answer, but Dutch was quick to close this. So I'll comment instead. The Earth has a mass of about 6 $\times$ 10^24 kg. That is 3 millionth's of the Sun's mass. Make the Earth a billion times more massive and you have potentially the mass of three million suns. We're talking about the kind of black hole that galaxies orbit around. Yours would be specifically around [75% as massive as the one at the center of the Milky Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittarius_A*#Central_black_hole).

Comment: So to answer in a few words: everything would occupy an unmeasurably small point in space. You would be able to see light from outside that black hole, but from a distance all anyone would see would be the gravitational lensing of the background, as well as the massive accretion disc.

Comment: And of course, being humans and made of really weak material, you'd be a thin layer on the "surface" (making possibly unwarranted assumptions about what's "inside" a black hole).  But for something reasonably close but still possible, look at Robert Forward's SF novel "Dragon's Egg", about life evolving on the surface of a neutron star.

Comment: "A billion".  We have some confusion here as to which billion we're using.  In some places a billion is 1000 million and in others it is a million million.  I don't think it materially changes the answer - either way you get a black hole.

Comment: "All atoms are still the same size/mass" - so where all the extra mass comes from? Dark matter?

Comment: Are objects bigger and made out of more atoms?

Answer (score 8):

## 1 million?

Let's scale up Earth's mass by **1 million** - or $10^6$.

Earth now weighs $5.972 \times 10^{24} \times10^6=5.972\times 10^{30}$ kg.

Earth Mass is now 3 times the solar mass. Earth collapses and turns into a star, though a rather odd duck as it contains a lot of heavy material. Life on earth stops. To feed its hunger for hydrogen and light elements, earth draws in Sol, Jupiter, Saturn, Neptune, devouring them, and actually, everything but pluto will be swallowed in a short period of astronomical time.

**Earth is now a very happy mainline star in the red spectrum,** close to turning supernova as the amount of post-iron stuff it is rather high - and that stuff isn't helpful for fusion power.

## 1 billion?!

Scaling up the earth by another 1000 would lead to problems: Beitalgueze, a red giant, is only $2\times 10^{31}$ kg, about 10 Solar masses. R136c, the most massive star, only is 230 times Sol - or $4.6\times 10^{32}$. You are asking for $6\times 10^{33}$, or 3000 suns.

Earth stops being a star and collapses into a black hole that has a Schwarzschild Radius of 8862 km. its gravitational pull is 5 070 787 072 m/s², and it will start to pull in other stars. Its first feast will be Proxima Centauri, spiraling in on the Black-Hole-Earth. At some point, it will join with the black hole in the center of the Milkyway and on the way feast on a sizeable portion of it. Together, the mega-black-hole will eat the rest of the Milkyway over a few solar lifetimes.

We get into even *more* hot water if we take the german definition of Billion: a Billion is 1000 Milliarden, which each is 1000 Millionen, so we end at 3-million-suns weight, or the ballpark of $6\times 10^{36}$ kg. Luckily, that's not yet in the area of the mass of the universe $10^{53}$ kg. Saggitarius A*, the black hole in the center of the Milkyway, is about $4.1\times10^6 solar$ masses. Our black hole earth is now just a bit lighter than that. In other words, Earth alone could do what Saggitarius A* does to the Milkyway, but now two of these star devouring monsters are in rather close proximity, and both are about equally massive. Black-hole-earth will stop spiraling slowly into Saggitarius and both will instead take a more direct collision course upon one another, eating stars at an accelerated rate until they merge. The effect will be the same as any two galaxies hitting one another: the whole system will be remodeled. Gone will be the two beautiful spiral arms and instead we'll likely end with a single blobby, elipsoid that is slowly pulled into the Saggitarius A*/Earth core, now in the ballpark of $9(\pm1.5)\times 10^6$ solar masses.

Comment: Nice numbers! Same thing I was saying just more... verbose? Numberouse?

Comment: @MarvinKitfox I pretty much pointed to roundabout where the area is where the numbers go bonkers by including 1 million

Comment: Don't forget that, according to the question, Earth's sun will also be 1 billion times more massive.  So the sun will be 1 billion solar masses.  The supermassive black hole at the center of the galaxy ("Sagittarius A*") is only approximately 4 million solar masses, so the sun will be about 250 more massive than Sagittarius A*.  When the sun merges with Sagittarius A*, Sagittarius A*'s mass will increase by 25,000%.

Comment: @cowlinator I blatantly ignored Sol's size increase, as earth's increase was enough to turn everything to a black blob.

Comment: That's fine.  I thought Sol's size was interesting info, so I commented.

Answer (score 3):

**black holes**

The Schwarzschild radius is the radius that tells when a mass will turn into a black hole. The sun is 1 solar mass big. A typical black hole has 3 to 10 solar mass. Although you start with the sun just a billion times larger, the gravity will pull everything inwards. Very quickly the Schwarzschild radius is reached, collapsing the star into a black hole.

The gravity change would also suck in the Earth and all other planets, but let's say they're the right distance away more or less. Some more googling told me a black hole is about a million times more massive than the Earth. As you enlarge it a billion times, the same would happen to the Earth as the sun and a black hole forms.

To see if this was accurate I found the sun is about 333.000 times the weight of the Earth. That means you will have 3003 times the mass of the sun if you inflate the Earth by a billion. Well enough for everything to collapse on itself and become a black hole.

Comment: I might've made a mistake at what weight the black holes generally form. Will check later. (A black hole can become lighter than the time it formed and stay a black hole). Still, it'll not be survivable even if no black holes form.

Answer (score 2):

Your planet will be massive enough to implode into a black hole *instantaneously*.

A billion times more massive, is about 10 times more massive than the [absolute ceiling limit for stellar sizes](https://www.space.com/41313-most-massive-star.html).

Answer (score 1):

## Unfortunately Impossible

I think you are stating that the laws of physics (which determine the size of atoms) stay the same but everything increase in size. In that case, the Inverse Square Law states that something double sized is 4 times more massive, etc. Judging from that, a significantly more massive creature would collapse under its own weight. However, if you need a situation using a minimum of handwaving, look for gravity to be a weaker force. That way, a more massive organism would not collapse as easily-although atoms might start acting very strangely...